# Dirichlet Kernel: Fourier coefficient question

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a project on the Dirichlet Kernel and I believe I've solved one of the problems that was assigned to me. If any one here could proof read my answer I would be very grateful.

**Problem:**

Insert the formula for the Fourier coecients $c_n$ of the 2-periodic function $f$ into the sum
\begin{equation}
s_N(x) = \sum _{n = -N} ^N c_n e^{inx}
\end{equation}

and hence show that

\begin{equation}
s_N(x) = \int _{-\pi} ^{\pi} f(t) D_N (x-t)dt
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
D_N = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum _{n = -N} ^N e^{inx}
\end{equation}

**Solution:**

According to the lecture notes the Fourier coefficient $c_n$ is given by the formula 
\begin{equation*}
c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) e ^{-i nt} dt
\end{equation*}
Now we get
\begin{align*}
s_N &= \sum ^N _{n = -N} c_n e^{inx} \\
&= \sum ^N _{n = -N} \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) e ^{-i nt} dt \cdot e^{inx} \\
&= \sum ^N _{n = -N} \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) e ^{in(x-t)} dt \\
&= \int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum ^N _{n = -N} e ^{in(x-t)} dt
\end{align*}
But we know that
\begin{equation*}
D_N(x)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \cdot \sum ^N _{n = -N} e^{inx}
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sum ^N _{n = -N} e ^{in(x-t)} dt &= \int ^{\pi} _{-\pi} f(t) \cdot D_N(x-t) dt
\end{align*}
which completes the proof.  $\square$

Thank you!

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: As formulated here, there's not more to it. The interesting part is writing $D_N(x)$ in closed form, i.e., without a $\sum$-sign. Having this expression in hand you can begin to understand why the inversion formula works.

Comment: Yes, it's very interesting to see what the graph of $D_N$ looks like as $N \to \infty$.  It looks more and more like a delta function, which helps to explain why $s_N(x)$ might converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.